# Ubuntu MATE battery indicator

Tags: 14.04, battery, customization, mate, ubuntu-mate

By default Ubuntu MATE battery indicator shows remaining time and percentage only when you hover on the battery icon.Otherwise it doesn't show any numbers:

[image]

Is it possible to make it behave like the Unity battery indicator which shows remaining time and percentage without hover or click.

Answer (score 7):

I could not make it behave exactly like the unity battery indicator, but I've found a solution that is, at least for me, enough.

- Right click on the panel.
- Click on "Add to Panel..."
- Select "Battery Charge Monitor"
- Click on "Add"

Another battery icon should appear. Right click on it.

- Click on "Preferences"
- Select: "Show time/percentage:"
- Close.

This should do it.

Comment: Any workaround to show both time and percentage at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

**Step A) Install**

```
sudo apt-get install mate-power-manager
```

**Step B) Configure**

System > Control Center > Power Management > General > Always display an icon [image]

**Step C) Restart Mate**

- Log out
- Log in again